# How can I deploy an Angular PWA to Firebase Hosting and Angular SSR to Firebase Functions with real people seeing the PWA and bots seeing SSR?

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular app that is a PWA using Firebase Hosting. I want to use SSR but only for bots and it seems like Firebase Functions can help accomplish that. I'd like to detect if the user is a bot and send them to SSR Firebase Functions if a bot and send them to PWA Firebase Hosting if a real person. Has anyone been able to do this?